# Replace part of a string using a regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
string = "width: 10px; height: 20px; whatever: 0px;";
```

I wish to change the height part to 50px and leave the rest in tact so that the end result looks like

```
string = "width: 10px; height: 50px; whatever: 0px;";
```

I have tried `string.replace("height: .*px;", "height: 50px;");` however this doesn't appear to work.

Can someone help me please

Comment: I would think if you include more context there might be a better solution than this.  Where is this string coming from and how is it being used?

Comment: Any info on the language you're using?

Comment: Where is the string information coming from?

Comment: @James The string is part of a HTML element style.cssText.  Changing the height directly doesn't appear to have any affect to I am trying a different method.  Tbh I am more interested in this as a learning exercise.

Comment: Why not adding a new rule in a later loaded css, with the same selector containing only the changed height attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guilherme's answer is partially correct: you do need to pass in a regular expression.  There's another problem with your regex, though: your repetition (`.*` right before `px`) is *greedy*: it will match everything it can.  So if you have `height: 20px; whatever: 0px`, it will greedily match `20px; whatever: 0px` (see how it consumed everything up to the last `px`?).  You will have to change it to a lazy match by appending the repetition with a `?`:

```
string.replace( /height: .*?px;/, "height: 50px;" );
```

To make it more robust still, you might want to account for a variable amount of whitespace, or if the height occurs at the end of the string (which I use a lookahead for):

```
string.replace( /height:\s*\d+px(?=;|$)/, 'height: 50px' );
```

Note I also used a digit specifier (`\d`) instead of the wildcard metacharacter (`.`).  Obviously this will only work if height will always be specified in integer units.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the regexp to make it non-greedy

```
"width: 10px; height: 20px; whatever: 0px;".replace(/height: .*?px;/, "height: 50px;")
```

Note the question mark after star - that tells the regexp engine to find the shortest possible match, i.e. `height: 20px;` instead of the longest, `height: 20px; whatever: 0px;`

Comment: I didn't realize you could call a method on a string literal like that!

Answer (score 0):

If you pass a string as the first argument of your `replace` method, it will try to replace your string literally. To use regular expressions, you must wrap it with the `/` character:

```
yourString = yourString.replace(/height: .*?px;/, "height: 50px;");
```

I agree with @JamesMontagne that maybe there is a better solution for what you are trying to do. It seems a bit hacky.